# Mysterious Magento Compression

Tags: javascript, css, magento, compression, mod-pagespeed

I need some help from the masters of Magento over here. My site seems to compress and combine CSS and JS files, and I'm trying to turn it off (because it takes forEVER to make CSS/JS changes). The compressed filenames look like such:

```
default,_default,_css,_styles.css+base,_default,_css,_widgets.css+default,_default,_ajaxcartpro,_css,_styles.css.pagespeed.cc.m7pIpU44Ks.css

prototype.js.pagespeed.ce.0jGH1h95bT.js
```

Which made me think that it was mod_pagespeed after looking at some StackOverflow answers. However, I can't find mod_pagespeed in my FTP (I used SFTP to check, it's not in etc/apache2/mods-available as the mod_pagespeed documentation suggests. Magento's own cacheing system has already been disabled, but it doesn't seem to change anything.

(A little backstory: the client came to me to continue the project after the previous agency bailed out on him. I've tried to contact that agency, but they seem to be quite unprofessional about it. So I need to find this out some other way).

My Questions: 
1) Does anyone know of other Magento modules that would compress the files as such? 
2) Or is it actually using Pagespeed and perhaps I'm looking in the wrong area?

Answer (score 0):

No idea how you're getting that without mod_pagespeed installed. It is definitely the result of mod_pagespeed.

Not knowing how you installed it, I can't help you with how to remove it, but if you set the initial Cache-Control: max-age to shorter, mod_pagespeed will update you changes faster. Say if you set it to 300 seconds, your resource will be served updated within 5min.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- disable pagespeed by adding the following into the pagespeed.conf:

  ```
  ModPagespeed off
  ```
- set pagespeed to ignore the rewrite_css and rewrite_js (https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/config_filters)
- load the url with pagespeed disabled: ie: ...com/?ModPagespeed=off
- flush pagespeed cache:

  ```
  sudo /bin/touch /var/mod_pagespeed/cache/cache.flush
  ```

Good resources:

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/configuration

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filters

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/faq

Also, you can turn off Magento's cache so you don't have to flush cache all the time.